# How to pattern match a script argument in Linux bash

Tags: bash

Basically, I have to create a bash script that analyzez the arguments of the script and if it's only one, proceeds to pattern match it. If it starts with a number, it says so, if it starts with a letter, it says so and if neither, it says the argument is a string. If you didn't provide an argument, it says you need 1, or if you provided 2 or more. Everything works, apart from the pattern matching itself. I always get the default case. What's wrong with it?

I gotta use case :( .

```
case $# in
    1) case $1 in
        /^?[0-9][a-zA-z]*$/) echo "Argument starts with number";;
        /^?[a-zA-z][a-zA-z]*$/) echo "Argument starts with letter";;
        *) echo "Argument is a string";;
        esac;;
    0) echo -n "You can't use 0 arguments"
        exit 1;;
    *) echo -n "You can't use 2 or more arguments"
        exit 1;;

esac

exit 0
```

EDIT: typing this in terminal gives me the default case: l@ubuntu:~/Documents$ ./e4_G_L.sh contor - maybe I wrote the argument wrong and the pattern matching works just fine?

Comment: There is a typo in the regex. I guess `a-zA-z` should be `a-zA-Z` (note the capital `Z` at the end).

Comment: Afaik the case statement only supports glob and not normal regexp pattern. Try using the `=~` for regex. eg. `[[ $1 =~ /^?[0-9][a-zA-z]*$/  ]]` which can be inside an if statement. I'm not good at regex so nothing for me on this question. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `case` only supports [globs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) (also known as *wildcards*).  To check regular expression as in your script you *could* use `[[ … =~ … ]]` but that would be overkill. Since you only want to check the first letter, globs are sufficient.

Also, I would rephrase the warning message. Tell the user what to do, not just *“You messed up. Good luck guessing on your next try.”*.

```
if [ $# != 1 ]; then
  echo "Expected 1 argument but found $#."
  exit 1
fi
case "$1" in
  [0-9]*) echo "Argument starts with number" ;;
  [a-zA-Z]*) echo "Argument starts with letter" ;;
  *) echo "Argument is a string";;
esac
```

Comment: This does seem to be what the question asks for, but the regex in the question seems to imply that `foo#` (which contains a non-alpha character) should be treated differently.  It's unclear what is actually wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```sh
shopt -s extglob
case $# in
    0)  echo "You can't use 0 arguments"
        exit 1
        ;;
    1)  case $1 in
            [0-9]+([[:alpha:]]) ) echo "A number followed by letters" ;;
            +([[:alpha:]]) ) echo "Only letters" ;;
            *) echo "Something else" ;;
        esac
        ;;
    *)  echo "You can't use 2 or more arguments"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody who bothered to help this lost soul :). It's a task for my Uni so no need for complex hints. The teacher knows what this is about so keeping it short. Ended up using the first answer.

Comment: Please upvote the useful solutions and accept the one that meets your requirements by clicking on the corresponding arrows.